# What's the best way to send data to a Omron controller?

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket

I am developing a web app that simulates a wire bending machine. I already have the app working but now I need to send the code (list of coordinates that will make a certain piece) to the machine controller.
What do you think it's the best way to do this? I'm thinking of WebSockets since the Omron's controller as socket instructions.
I used a link instead of the IP adress so I could test that my code could read the content correctly and it did.
My code in javascript:

```
function abrirSocket()
{ 
    ws = new WebSocket('wss://192.168.250.1');
    CheckBlankSpace();
    var linhas = document.getElementById("txtMaq").length;
    var txtMaq = document.getElementById("txtMaq");
    var content = "";
    for(var i=0; i <=linhas-1; i++)
    {
    //get the code to send to the machinet 
         content += txtMaq[i].value + "\n";
    };
        
    ws.onopen = function ()
    { 
      ws.send(content); 
    }

    ws.onmessage = function(msg) 
    { 
        alert(content);
    }       

    ws.onerror = function (error)
    { 
        alert(`[error] Não foi possível estabelecer uma conexão`);
    } 

    ws.onclose = function () 
    {  if (event.wasClean) 
      {
        alert(`[close] Conexão terminada, code=${event.code}`);
      }
      else 
      {
        alert('[close] Connection died');
      } 
    } 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to look at OMRON Fins Protocol. This is (Omron) standard and well documented thing supported by many Omron controllers, also the cheaper one via serial bus.
You can read/write values and more. It can use UDP or TCP connection there (both have pros and cons).
I have no idea about java script library, but I used Qt and Python binding library for this.